# How can I import Electrum addresses into a Core wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum, windows, private-key-import

I have been running all my BTC transactions through Electrum, but recently installed the 0.14.0 Core client and would like to move to that. I managed to export my ~40 private keys from Electrum, but how do I properly import them into the Core client?